# Linq query- Collection within a dictonary

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, linq

I am trying to get result from a dictionary using linq but I am not sure how to do it.
I am trying to write a linq query to get the employee name,salary of the empId=2. Please correct me with the right linq query.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, List<Employee>> empDic = new Dictionary<int, List<Employee>>();
        var emp = new List<Employee>();
        emp.Add(new Employee{EmpID = 1,Name="affsa",Salary=2000})  ;
        emp.Add(new Employee { EmpID = 2, Name = "axy",Salary=3000 });
        emp.Add(new Employee { EmpID = 3, Name = "xyz",Salary=4000 });
        empDic.Add(1,emp);

        var selectedEmpDetails = empDic.Values
                                       .Select(r => r.Where(f => f.EmpID ==2))
                                       .ToList();          
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
var selectedEmpDetails = empDic.SelectMany(x=>x.Value)
                               .Where(x=>x.EmpId==2)
                               .Select(x=> new { Name = x.Name, Salary = x.Salary });
```

Initially we flatten the values of the dictionary in a list of `Employee` objects.

Then we select the object with the `EmpId` equals to 2.

Last we select it's name and salary properties.

Answer (score 2):

I would use SelectMany() function in your case so that I get a flattened list of Employee instances. Then try to get the first Employee instance that matches the employee id (if any) with the FirstOrDecault() function.

```
var selectedEmpDetails = empDic.Values.SelectMany(r => r.Where(f => f.EmpID == 2)).FirstOrDefault();
if(selectedEmpDetails != null)
{
    string employeeName = selectedEmpDetails.Name;
    int employeeSalary = selectedEmpDetails.Salary;
}
```